# If A and B are 6x6 matrices with det(A) = -10 and det(B) =5, how do i find det(-A), det(3A) and especially det(A^t B^-1)?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

So i have these two matrices where all i know is that they are 6 by 6 and I have their determinants, how would I work out the above? I know I need to use, or can use, the properties of determinants but I feel like there might be more to it than it being as simple as multiplying by -1 or 3. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some of these [properties of the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant) to help you out.

Comment: So i would just use property 5 for the first two?

Comment: Yes, and a combination of properties 2, 3, and 4 for the third problem.